# Connected sum of a torus and a real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

My question is really basic. I was reading on the Massey's Book of algebraic topology on the connected sum of the torus and real projective plane, I felt a little confused his explanation.
Someone can explain to me Or at least give a reference where I can find this calculation?

Comment: Calculation of *what*?

Comment: Please summarize what Massey did in his book.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have Massey's book, I'm not sure what he does, and you haven't given any clue as to what it is that confuses you. But there is a proof that the connected sum of a torus and a projective plane is homeomorphic to the connected sum of three projective planes on page 9 of [these notes](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/topology/chap03.pdf). All the definitions are given earlier in that chapter.